# Simple LAN Base Offline Webpage for keep recording of Data

Tags: html, lan

I don't have much knowledge about servers or anything this all but have little base knowledge about HTML or LAN Networking.

As i mention in Title. I just want one simple web-page for entry our data, such as call time, location, description, caller and receiver and i know this all can do thru HTML base webpage design but what i want is share that web-page thru LAN (Not Online) for key-in 3-4 persons in different computer. What type of software (Application) i have to use and the setup.

I have a 5 PC Connected with LAN with main PC (normal windows 7 but if need can change as Server also) and i just want Web-Page or HTML Page all data store and share from the Main PC to others workers PC.

Thank You in Advance for your Amazing Answer :)

Comment: You can use XAMPP and use your network IP to show the page on other computers.

Comment: Thank You @PatrickSimard for the quick response. I will try and let you know about my result also. If any problem hope you will be there for me ;)

Comment: sure thing. Let me know how it goes an I will post this as the main awnser so you can accept it.

Comment: When install have some problem as need to disable UAC (User Account Control) and detect Antivirus?????? but after making some configuration thru config..... It's work like CHARM

Thank You @PatrickSimard It's Work Like Charm and Sorry for late reply because i was testing for last few days. Until now I didn't stuck or didn't get any trouble, if i get then i will mention  you somewhere ;) Thank You Man!! You are so Great :>3

Comment: Glad it worked out Sagar, I posted the full answer. Accept it at your earliest convenience. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Already and Thank You for making others more useful (Specially those who just start learning about Networking and Database) as ME. Thank You Man @PatrickSimard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal you need to set up a server environment on your computer. The best way to do it worry free would be to use an already bundled server like XAMPP.

It's very easy to host website on xampp server by following those steps.

1. Install xampp in your computer/server
2. Place web pages in xampp servers htdocs folder
3. To make default path of the server edit configuration of xampp and
   submit path of your web folder
4. Now start apache (and mysql if needed) and try to run localhost/yourwebdirectory
   once run without error your server is running fine. You can also run it by using your network IP.
5. Now check firewall and allow port 80 (If you require database, setup port 3306 as well)

If you ever want to make it public, you can use a no-ip domain and point that to your IP Make sure the firewall allow public access.